# jquery ui-sortable events, beforeStop getting wrong index() values

Tags: jquery-ui

We have a list of objects using jquery ui-sortable for the ui to implement drag and drop re-order for our users.

I wanted to add a non-draggable row on the top and prevent any rows from being dragged above it.  Using examples I found here, I implemented some event handlers on the configuration, starting with beforeStop.

My problem is that, on occasion, I get into the beforeStop event handler and ui.item.index() is returning the wrong result.  If you get the drag *just right*, ui.item.index() returns 1, even though it's going to drop it in the 0 slot.  And rather than pushing what's in 0 down one, it seems to pick a seemingly random spot down the list (though this may be related to the lag in rendering ui.placeholder).

I've found posts saying that index() is either 0 or 1 based depending on when you're moving up or down.  In this case, I'm always dragging up with a disabled handle on my 0th item.  So it sounds like it should always be 0-based.

I haven't found any articles about index() just getting it wrong, though.  Any ideas?

These are my handlers:

```
beforeStop: function (ev, ui)
{   // beforeStop apparently is not reliable for cancel, so leave some state for stop
    if (ui.item.index() == 0) // sometimes returns the wrong number
        ui.item.badmove = true;
},
stop: function(ev, ui)
{
    if (ui.item.badmove)
        $(this).sortable("cancel");
},
```

Comment: Maybe it's related to if you drag up and then drift down a little?  Still can't explain the random placement of the top element after.

Comment: I've tried every method I could find on various oflow article, but the one that works for me (specific to not moving to the top) is using the beforeStop event and comparing ui.item.clientTop == 0.  It looks like $(this).children[0] is still pre-shift, too, if you wanted to compare to .clientTop of an immovable item elsewhere in the list.

Comment: Strike that.  ui.item[0].clientTop appears to always be 0.  Damn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually gave up on trying to make ui-sortable have any rows that were immovable and instead styled a separate list immediately above to look like the sortable but not participating in it.

ui-sortable was just too flaky.  I couldn't find any way to get deterministic behavior out of any of the events.